# Eclipse Oxygen - e4xmi editor no more available

Tags: eclipse, editor, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-marketplace

Seems the e4xmi editor is no more available in my Eclipse Oxygen installation.

If I right-click on the e4xmi file and choose "Open with", I see only generic text editors.

I tried to re-install the e4xmi editor from market place searching for "Eclipse 4 Tools: Application Model Editor" and can't find it (tried several keywords).

Tried to install directly from https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-4-tools-application-model-editor (dragging the install button on eclipse). But it just opens the Market Place showing other results.

Someone had the same problem? I'm going to copy the eclipse installation from a coleague's computer, but I would like to solve on my installation.

Evironment:
Desktop Win7
Eclipse Oxygen
JDK 1.8

Answer (score 1):

You install this using 'Help > Install New Software...' and choosing the main update site for your release (`http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen`).

Choose 'Eclipse e4 Tools Developer Resources'  in the 'General Purpose Tools' section.

You should end up with the `org.eclipse.e4.tools.emf.editor3x` plugin among others being installed, this contains the editor.